# Issue querying results from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We have a 2 field search form. The first field is a case selectbox and the values are populating in the field box. We have inspected element and can see the field values as the actual names in the select box. The 2nd box we have is a text box associated with city/state. The idea is that the first select box contains categories and the user would select a category and input their city/state and would be able to search the database for any results that match their category selected and the city/state inputed. As of right now the results are searching the city correct however the categories is either not be querying correctly or not being filtered correctly because we are getting multiple results which include categories of those not being selected from the select box in the search results.

Here is the code for the select box:

```
function gmw_fl_fields_dropdown($gmw, $id, $class) {

$total_fields = ( isset($gmw['profile_fields']) ) ? $gmw['profile_fields'] : array();

if( isset($gmw['profile_fields_date']) ) array_unshift($total_fields, $gmw['profile_fields_date']);

echo '<div id="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'">';

foreach ( $total_fields as $field_id ) {

    $field_data = new BP_XProfile_Field ($field_id);
    $fieldName = explode(' ', $field_data->name);
    $fieldName = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$fieldName[0]);

    $get_field = (isset($_GET[$fieldName . '_' . $field_id])) ? $_GET[$fieldName . '_' . $field_id] : '';
    $get_field_to = (isset($_GET[$fieldName . '_' . $field_id. '_to'])) ? $_GET[$fieldName . '_' . $field_id. '_to'] : '';

    $children = $field_data->get_children ();

    switch ($field_data->type) {

        case 'datebox':
            echo '<div class="editfield field_'.$field_id.' datebox">';
            echo '<span class="label">Age Range (min - max)</span>';
            echo '<input size="3" type="text" name="'. $fieldName . '_' . $field_id.'" value="' . $get_field . '" placeholder="Min" style="width:10%" />';
            echo '&nbsp;-&nbsp;';
            echo '<input size="3" type="text" name="'. $fieldName . '_' . $field_id . '_to" value="' . $get_field_to . '" placeholder="Max" style="width:10%" />';
            echo '</div>';
            break;

        case 'multiselectbox':
        case 'selectbox':
            case 'selectbox':
            echo '<div class="editfield_'.$field_id.' selectbox">';
            echo '<select>';
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $child->name = trim ($child->name);
                $selected = ($child->name == $get_field )? "selectd='selected'": "";
                echo '<option type="selectbox"  name="'. $fieldName . '_' . $field_id. '[]"  value="'.$child->name.'">'.$child->name.'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            echo '</div>';
            break;
```

Here is the code for the query function:

```
function gmw_fl_query_fields($gmw) {
global $bp, $wpdb;
$total_fields = false;

$total_fields = ( isset( $gmw['profile_fields'] ) ) ? $gmw['profile_fields'] : array();



if( isset( $gmw['profile_fields_date'] ) && !empty( $gmw['profile_fields_date'] ) ) array_unshift( $total_fields, $gmw['profile_fields_date'] );

if ( !isset($total_fields) || empty($total_fields) ) return;

$empty_fields = array();
$userids = false;

foreach ($total_fields as $field_id) {
    $field_data = new BP_XProfile_Field ($field_id);
    $fieldName = explode(' ', $field_data->name);
    $fieldName = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$fieldName[0]);
    $children = $field_data->get_children ();

    $value = ( isset($_GET[$fieldName . '_'. $field_id]) ) ? $_GET[$fieldName . '_'. $field_id] : '';
    $to = ( isset($_GET[$fieldName . '_' . $field_id. '_to']) ) ?  $_GET[$fieldName . '_' . $field_id. '_to'] : '';

    if ($value) array_push($empty_fields, $value);

    if( $value || $to || $children ) {

        switch ($field_data->type) {

            case 'selectbox':

                $sql = "SELECT user_id from {$bp->profile->table_name_data}";
                $sql .= " WHERE field_id = $field_id ";

            break;

            case 'radio':

                $sql = "SELECT user_id from {$bp->profile->table_name_data}";
                $sql .= " WHERE field_id = $field_id ";
                $like = array();

                foreach ($value as $curvalue)
                    $like[] = "value = '$curvalue' OR value LIKE '%\"$curvalue\"%' ";
                $sql .= ' AND ('. implode (' OR ', $like). ')';
            break;
        }//switch //

    $results = $wpdb->get_col($sql, 0);

        if ( !is_array($userids) ) $userids = $results; else $userids = array_intersect($userids, $results);

    } // if value //
} // for eaech //

/* build SQL filter from profile fields results - member ids array */
if ( isset($userids) && !empty($userids) ) return $userids;
/* if no results and profile fields are not empty - buba is going to stop the function */
else if ( !empty($empty_fields) ) return "buba";
```

}

The kicker is this...the query function for the case radio button works like a charm! But we have 30+ categories in the drop down select box and it is just a lot cleaner looking than 30+ radio buttons in the search form.

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated as we can't figure what the correct statement needs to be get the case select box to query right.